# WL 6.0.0.1 Installation Manager install for Tomcat7 fails create Derby tables and fails put worklight-jee-library.jar into /lib folder of Tomcat

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-server

I personally tried the installation process of our Consumer WL 6.0.0.1 IBM Installation Manager Repository version on my Mac OSx 10.8 with IBM Installation Manager .macosx.cocoa.x86_64_1.6.3001.20130528_1750. A colleague reports the same problem from a Linux install.

When selecting Tomcat 7 and new Derby as install destination, the Installation Manager only puts the WL Application Center things into the Tomcat web.xml and webapps folder etc, but fails to do the necessary steps to deploy a developed WL application right away:

- we had to hunt down the worklight-jee-library.jar and put it ourselves into the /lib folder of the Tomcat
- we checked the Derby DB that the Installation Manager created, the databases were there, but no tables were created in there by the Installation Manager. So we had to execute the table sql scripts ourselves manually.

Is this problem with the Installation Manager and Tomcat + Derby known?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The IBM Installation Manager for Worklight 6.0.0.0 currently DOES NOT **install** Worklight.

What it actually does is extract the Worklight framework files and Ant task scripts, which you then need to configure and run, for the framework files as well as your Worklight project's .war file to be deployed on the Application Server. I believe the database is being created/filled via the Ant task script as well.

The process is well documented [in the Information Center for Worklight 6.0](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r0m0/topic/com.ibm.worklight.help.doc/admin/c_installation.html).

Comment: Oh. Sorry we didn't assume that this had changed so much. Since it worked so fine with WL 5.0.6 Server, Tomcat and Derby in the past we assumed to follow the same process for WL 6.0.0.1 and did not assume that there was a step back. The IM does something with the Derby database, but somehow there is a problem with the tables. App can be deployed without error - deploying adapter we get: `Failed to deploy adapter 'AirportDataAdapter.adapter'. The 'adapter' version 'null' is different than the version of Worklight Server '6.0.0'. Use Worklight Studio '6.0.0' to build and deploy the application.`

Comment: The install doc of 6.0.0.1 is a little confusing (spread across many pages), maybe especially when you come from 5.0.6. Several people here at the project read through the pages and nobody got the fact that Ant is not optional anymore but now the default/only way to install a Wl 6.0.0.1 server, to create databases and to copy Wl J2EE jar over. - especially it is not mentioned in the documentation that the Ant task is actually "creating/fixing the derby databases" and "copying the WL J2EE jar over to the tomcat/lib" - so we all assumed a bug in the Install Manager and did that manually.